# Python function that accepts a path to an input file

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a python function that accepts a path to an input file (just a single file and not a directory) and returns a Hamiltonian matrix. I already have a script that creates the matrix, but i'm a bit unsure how to write the function. I'm running pycharm and python 2.7

Should I go with:

```
f = open('myFile.xyz', 'r')
obj.writeTo(f)
f.close()
```

or something like

```
def your_function_filename(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return your_function_filename(f)
```

I'm trying to go with something that has the easiest user interface.

EDIT: For example - I have a text.txt file with the following two lines:

```
x=3
y=4
```

I also have a python script saying:

```
print (x+y)
print (x-y)
```

Instead of defining x and y in the python script I was to have another python script that says put text.txt through the python script and output the result in another python script.

Comment: When you say "user interface", do you mean code readability? If so, to me, the first one is much more easier to understand

Comment: Did you mean your second function to be recursive?  The first call will pass a string, but the second call (from the `return`) passes a file object.  Not sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: I'm trying to get the function to accept a path to an input file (not a directory), have the input file go through another python script that creates a Hamiltonian matrix, and then has the output of the Hamiltonian. I think I'm getting confused with the different steps I have to do.

Comment: I made an edit to my original question to highlight what I am trying to do